# How to render (fast) text on path?

Tags: linux, vector, rendering

How to render (to image) text on path with any renderer working on linux?

Like this: [text on path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiFUr.png).

Performance is important.

Comment: What did you find when you researched this, and why were they not suitable?

Comment: cairo, imageMagick - I could not find examples of what I want. I was able to draw it in SVG and see from Inkscape and Firefox.

Comment: SVG is a vector format. You should look for an SVG library. You don't "render" an svg when you're producing it. The client does that.

Comment: I tried librsvg, but it can't. I looking alternatives, but may be there is another way other than svg..

Comment: What do you mean it can't? You're aware that SVG images are (possibly compressed) text files, right? (Looks like XML). Please do more research. http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/text/svg/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

I'm on a Debian Squeeze system with the [python-cairo](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-cairo) package installed.  If I run the warped text [example](http://www.koders.com/python/fid1D133FBF06047430F8E3D2D9A02F5CDB676747E0.aspx?s=file:warpedtext.py) it provides (85 lines of Python):

```
python /usr/share/doc/python-cairo/examples/warpedtext.py
```

it produces a warpedtext.png file like this:

[image]

I imagine it'd be fairly easy to modify/adapt/port the example.

Long answer:

There are two things you need to do this.

1. The ability to generate the transforms which will place individual letters with the correct position and orientation along the path.  This is basic 2D transform geometry.
2. The ability to render transformed characters/font glyphs with a decent level of quality (sub-pixel precision, antialiasing etc).

For the latter, I'd be looking at one of

- Qt's [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainterpath.html) (this [example](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_do_i_make_text_follow_the_line_curve_and_angle_of_the_qpainterpath) seems to be exactly what you want, but see also [this one](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/demos-deform.html)).
- [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/tutorial/#L1understandingtext) (another [example](http://mces.blogspot.com/2008/11/text-on-path-with-cairo.html)).
- [Anti-Grain Geometry](http://www.antigrain.com/demo/index.html#PAGE_DEMO_raster_text).